# Unable to get VCard using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am unable to get the VCard information using XMPPFramework using this code

```
XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@myserver", myId]];
XMPPvCardTemp *vcard = [[DBChatManager shareInstance].xmppvCardTempModule vCardTempForJID:jid shouldFetch:YES];
```

it return nil in response but in logging i seen that it fetch the VCard. While i can update and create VCard successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i found out that in class XMPPvCardTempModule.m following lines are commented by my team member

```
XMPPvCardTemp *vCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempCopyFromIQ:iq];
if (vCardTemp != nil)
{
    [self _updatevCardTemp:vCardTemp forJID:[iq from]];

    return YES;
}
```

after uncommenting above lines i am able to get the VCard detail against a JID in

```
- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule
    didReceivevCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp
                 forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
```

and use it according to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

After Authenticating use XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage and XMPPvCardTempModule

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    [self goOnline];
    if ([xmppStream isAuthenticated]) {
        NSLog(@"authenticated");
        xmppvCardStorage = [[XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];
        xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
        [xmppvCardTempModule activate:[self xmppStream]];
        [xmppvCardTempModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [xmppvCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:[sender myJID] ignoreStorage:YES];
    }

}

- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule didReceivevCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid{

        XMPPvCardTemp *vCard = [xmppvCardStorage vCardTempForJID:jid xmppStream:xmppStream];
        NSLog(@"%@", vCard.description);
    }
```